# Is it possible to split an AWK command in multiple lines, without having an error?

Tags: shell, awk, sh, indentation

I've an AWK command that is pretty long

```
awk -v AWK_SECTION_TITLE="$SECTION_TITLE" -v AWK_ADDED="$ADDED" -v AWK_CHANGED="$CHANGED" -v AWK_FIXED="$FIXED" -v AWK_REMOVED="$REMOVED" 'NR=='"$CHANGELOG_INSERT_LINE"'{
    print AWK_SECTION_TITLE
    ....
```

I would like to know if it is possible to split this first part -where I set the variables for awk scope- into multi lines, with some backslashes or any other syntax.

I tried this approach:

```
awk
    \ -v AWK_SECTION_TITLE="$SECTION_TITLE"
    \ -v AWK_ADDED="$ADDED"
    ...
```

and this was the error

```
usage: awk [-F fs] [-v var=value] [-f progfile | 'prog'] [file ...]
script.sh: line 65:  -v: command not found
```

I tried this approach:

```
awk -v AWK_SECTION_TITLE="$SECTION_TITLE"
    \ -v AWK_ADDED="$ADDED" -v AWK_CHANGED="$CHANGED"
```

and this was the error

```
awk: no program given
```

I tried this approach:

```
awk -v AWK_SECTION_TITLE="$SECTION_TITLE"
    \ -v AWK_ADDED="$ADDED" -v AWK_CHANGED="$CHANGED"
```

and this was the error

```
awk: no program given
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You imported multiple variables, why not `CHANGELOG_INSERT_LINE` too?

Comment: I tried with \ and it didn't work, that's why I'm asking how to do it.

Comment: I don't need to import CHANGELOG_INSERT_LINE, I need it just as a check on where to insert my code.

Comment: The backslash escapes the linebreak, so it has to go on the line that is being continued, not the next line.

Comment: Overwork makes you blind.. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add an escape it's to escape the character that follows it. Putting it at the start of a line escapes whatever character follows it on that line instead of the command-terminating newline you want to escape at the end of the preceding line.

Do:

```
cmd foo \
    bar
```

instead of:

```
cmd foo
\    bar
```